# Is there a way to get a list containing only data from a single attribute in a spring boot application using mongorepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have made an employee register application to record attendance details of an employee. So there is 2 tables one containing employee details and another for attendance. The employee entity and its data members are as follows

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private Integer empId;
    private String name;
    private Integer wageRate;
    private Integer overtimeRate;
    private Integer dueAmount;
```

we can use mongorepository to replace sql codes like findNameByEmpId() like that. I want to know whether there is a way to get all the empIds in a single list with no conditions or anything.

I tried the function `findAllEmpId()` and it didn't work. All I want is the query `SELECT EmpId FROM Employee;` to work instead of fetching all the details and then reducing it to the wanted form. Please help.